# how to program if score equals 50 or below minus 2 points?

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to get it right just can't seem to get the right line.

```
if (score is 50 or below) then (-2 from score)
```

how would I do this correctly - programatically!?

Comment: May I suggest you find yourself a nice tutorial on the basics of the Objective-C programming language. If you don't know how to write a simple `if` statement, you are never going to be able to write an app. Spend time now on the basics and save yourself a lot of time down the road. Good luck.

Comment: @maddy thats your opinion! its better to ask a question and be a fool for 10 minutes than to never ask and remain a fool forever! This is how I learn, so you can either answer the question, or be nice!

Comment: I was being nice. That was an honest, friendly, sincere, meant-to-be-helpful comment. It really is important to learn the basics of the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple if statement...

```
if(score <= 50)
    score = score - 2;
```

Quick google search provides some useful [docs](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks, the thing is google doesn't display the same search results to everyone that correlate to the each other, can I have the link to where you found that?